# specify and run *particular* version of geth (goethe) on my machine, with more than one source

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum, build-from-source

At the moment I'm playing around with- or rather "*conducting some experiments*"- with JPM's `quorum`.

On my machine I have multiple versions of `geth` (i.e. `goethe`) installed.

I'm fairly confident that when I issue the following terminal command:

```
geth --testnet --rpc --mine
```

what is executed is the version of `goethe` that lives in my `$GOPATH`, i.e.:

```
/Users/s.matthew.english/go/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum
```

(sub-question: *Is the above conjecture accurate*?)

**However...**

What I want to do is run the JPM `quorum` version of `goethe`, that lives in a different directory, namely:

```
/Users/s.matthew.english/clients/quorum/0.0_quorum/quorum
```

Is it possible to specify on start-up which version of `goethe` is executed?

---

**Edit**

Even though I was in the `quorum` directory, the output of `which geth` was the one on my `$GOPATH`

[image]

Comment: Workaround ("*quick hack*") is to just use a docker container

Comment: What do you mean by `goethe`, or have I missed something about release names? Or is that JPM's name for Geth? (I'm reading `goethe` as Goethe (pron: "Ger-ter"), i.e. the German bloke... )

Comment: it's a kind of social experiment- I just think it would be funny if I could get many people calling `geth` as `goethe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm fairly confident that when I issue the following terminal command: `geth --testnet --rpc --mine` what is executed is the version of goethe that lives in my $GOPATH

This is a bash command so what program gets executed is determined by the $PATH environment var (only the go compiler is concerned with $GOPATH, not bash).

You can check what gets executed by doing `which geth`, it will print the full path.

Comment: thanks for the feedback! so- I just added an update to the OP, even though I was in the `quorum` directory, `which geth` output the one on my `$GOPATH`, maybe I can specify which one to use by putting something in my `~/.zshrc`?

Comment: If you want one `geth` command to give you an option which one to run, you could make an interactive bash script named `geth` and put it in /usr/local/bin (or somewhere that has high priority in your $PATH). Then in the bash script use the full paths to the particular geth versions.

Comment: so if I install it, or link to it, at a place higher up in my directory structure, as in- closer to the `~`, or w/e, the top of the top, that will take precedence over the one installed at `/Users/s.matthew.english/go`?

Comment: It may be that the directory in your $GOPATH is also included in your $PATH.  As to the .zshrc, look at docs on Z shell.

Comment: my `$PATH` looks like this `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/build-tools/19.1.0:/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools:/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/tools:/usr/local/opt/gradle/bin:/usr/local/opt/maven/bin:/usr/local/opt/ant/bin:/Users/s.matthew.english/.nvm/versions/node/v7.4.0/bin:/Users/s.matthew.english/go/bin:/Users/s.matthew.english/.rbenv/shims:/Users/s.matthew.english/.rbenv/bin:/Users/s.matthew.english/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin`, there isn't `geth` on there

Comment: The precedence is determined by your $PATH (directories are prioritized by their order in $PATH).

Comment: The first place the shell finds a geth executable is probably in /Users‌​/s.matthew.english/g‌​o/bin, which is in the $PATH. So that's the one that gets executed.

Comment: ahaaa, cool man- thank you- I never knew that before :) so then if I just put quorum up higher into that- then it will find quorum first- and then I can move it back? or... what was that thing you said about making a bash script for it or something?

Comment: You could put the quorum directory as the first one in the $PATH, and then restart your shell (ie. open a new terminal), then quorum will be invoked instead. Or a bash script could prompt you (which one? A or B) every time.

Comment: but then- I would have to put that bash script high up in my `$PATH` right? at least before the directories that contain `geth`- man but what about this- if I call `.geth` from inside one of the `go-ethereum` directories, or the quorum directory, it doesn't work- so how can it be a command on the `$PATH` but not "locally" in the same dir?

Comment: man I've been trying to do that- but- [to no avail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45787522/path-macos-move-directory-up-in-the-hierarchy-to-prefer-execution-of-particul)

Answer (score 1):

Download the binary file for your OS from here:  https://geth.ethereum.org

Create a shell/bash file that contains instructions for starting up geth like in this example which I use for the ropsten testnet on Ubuntu. Make any changes as needed for the appropriate network you want to use as well as change/add any flags as needed. Be sure to change the directory path to match your local file system.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "STARTING GETH ROPSTEN TESTNET"

/home/rfikki/projects/ethereum-develop-ropsten/geth \
    --testnet \
    --syncmode "fast" \
    --cache "1024" \
    --port "30303" \
    --identity "Homestead Geth Ropsten Network" \
    --datadir "/home/rfikki/projects/ethereum-develop-ropsten/testnet-data" \
    --jspath "/home/rfikki/projects/ethereum-develop-ropsten/javascript" \
    --unlock "0" \
    --password "/home/rfikki/projects/ethereum-develop-ropsten/password.txt" \
    --shh \
    --rpc \
    --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" \
    --rpcport "8545" \
    --rpcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,shh,txpool,net,web3,personal" \
    --rpccorsdomain "*" \
    --verbosity 3 \
    --bootnodes "enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303,enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303" \
    console 2>> /home/rfikki/projects/ethereum-develop-ropsten/startup-geth-ropsten.log
```

Comment: I tried it with specifying the full path to the directory where I have quorum in stalled, similar to what you've done with `/home/rfikki/projects/ethereum-develop-ropsten/geth`, but it didn't work

Comment: This particular bash file works for me on the Ubuntu OS.

Comment: do you also have a version of `goethe` installed on your `$GOPATH`?